# Can I use $++ PHP in a foreach loop to increment the 'as' index?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

If I wanted to create a `foreach` loop that would add every second player to team A or team B

```
foreach ( $selectedplayers as $selectedplayer ) {
        TeamA[] = $selectedplayer;
        $selectedplayer++;
        TeamB[] = $selectedplayer; 
}
```

I know I can do it with a `for` loop but was interested to see if it could be done this way.

Comment: There's no increment in a foreach loop because it steps through every item in the array

Comment: Ok, thought that might be the case, thanks.

Comment: no you can't.
check this out (the iterator method)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20479610/php-array-get-next-key-value-in-foreach

Comment: foreach is used to iterrate through all elements in array, for your case use for or check $key % 2 == 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  `$selectedplayer` is the actual value of each element.  Either use your own counter:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ( $selectedplayers as $selectedplayer ) {
        if($i % 2 === 0)) {
            $TeamA[] = $selectedplayer;
        } else {
            $TeamB[] = $selectedplayer; 
        }
        $i++;
}
```

Or use the `$key` of the array if the keys are sequential (or at least odd, even pattern):

```
foreach ( $selectedplayers as $key => $selectedplayer ) {
        if($key % 2 === 0)) {
            $TeamA[] = $selectedplayer;
        } else {
            $TeamB[] = $selectedplayer; 
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I hadn't thought about the if statement option.