# How can we get key of next element key with foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting xml array from an api and when please see it below
I am using this foreach loop.

```
                    foreach ($event->raidstatus as $status){
                          //i want to get name and cound i tried $status->name but failed
                          //and when i did print_r($status) then got array
                          echo '<pre>'; print_r($status); exit;
                    }
```

This is print_r results

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [status0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [id] => 0
            [name] => Bestätigt
            [count] => 1
        )

    [status1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Angemeldet
            [count] => 3
        )

    [status2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Abgemeldet
            [count] => 4
        )

    [status3] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Ersatzbank
            [count] => 0
        )

    [required] => 40
)
```

Please help me to get results Thanks

Comment: Can you show the XML as it looks as though the elements are called `status0`, `status1` etc.

Comment: yes see this http://78.47.206.152/raidplaner/api.php?function=calevents_list

Comment: this answer will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20479610/php-array-get-next-key-value-in-foreach

Comment: Sorr i did not understand can you help me out on there and give me answer related to my loop please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to fetch the data from the `<status...>` elements, you are just 1 level short in your `foreach()` loop.

```
foreach ($event->raidstatus as $status){
```

is fetching the whole `<raidstatus>` element, you want all of the child nodes (using `children()` in this code) to get at the name elements...

```
foreach ($event->raidstatus->children() as $status){
    echo '<pre>'.$status->name.PHP_EOL;
}
```